# Selecting the right CRS for a KML file in Jupyter

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas, jupyter-notebook

[image]

I'm working with Ipyleaflet to display a KML file in a Jupyter Notebook

I have the following in a cell:

```
import fiona
import geopandas as gpd
from ipyleaflet import GeoData, Map, basemaps


fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers["LIBKML"] = "rw"
# gdf = gpd.read_file("file.kml")
gdf = gpd.read_file(fc.selected)


CENTER = (
    gdf.dissolve() 
    .centroid.get_coordinates()
    .stack()[::-1].tolist()
)

m = Map(center=CENTER, basemap=basemaps.Esri.WorldStreetMap, zoom=15)

gdata = GeoData(
    geo_dataframe=gdf,
    style={"color": "black", "fillColor": "red", "fillOpacity": 0.8},
)

m.add(gdata)
```

The output is in the screenshot. I'm getting a map that looks right but I'm also getting:

```
/tmp/ipykernel_1405/4270214913.py:13: UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'centroid' are likely incorrect. Use 'GeoSeries.to_crs()' to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation. .centroid.get_coordinates()
```

How do I search for and add the appropriate CRS?

Comment: KML only has one CRS ( http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/0/LonLat84_5773 ) as defined in Annex A of the specification ~ http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/12-007r2/12-007r2.html

Comment: @TomazicM, its a different question, a follow up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely ignore that warning in this case, you just need to center the map, not be super accurate. And you need the center coordinates in a geographic CRS to pass to ipyleaflet anyway.

To ignore that warning:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="Geometry is in a geographic CRS")

rest of your code
```

Comment: Can you explain "And you need the center coordinates in a geographic CRS to pass to ipyleaflet anyway" - sorry, but I'm pretty new to this

Comment: You pass geographic coordinates (latitude, longitude in decimal degrees) to the ipyleaflet map to set the centre, not projected coordinates (northings, eastings in metres/feet).